# Indicator-Weather hangs when trying to change Location

Tags: indicator, preferences, weather

I have always used Weather Indicator (indicator-weather) for all my weather-related needs on Ubuntu, since 10.04.  I now use 11.10 and have indicator-weather installed from the Ubuntu repositories.  I recently moved from New Orleans, Louisiana to a town called Central just outside of Baton Rouge, Louisiana.  I tried to removed my New Orleans location and add my new one using the programs Preferences dialog.  It allows me to remove my current location, and even allows me to select "Central, Louisiana, United States" by entering "Central, LA" and hitting the "search" button. But when I do that, the application hangs and goes gray and never ever updates.  This is driving me crazy.  I cannot seem to find how to manually change my location in any config file, although I don't know much about this app and I am not sure where it stores this info.  Things I have tried so far include:

1. Change Location as mentioned above
2. Use the more common "Baton Rouge" location choices using the same steps mentioned   above.
3. I have uninstalled the application AND also uninstalled the dependency python-pywapi using both the sudo apt-get remove AND the sudo apt-get purge commands and reinstalling the application.
4. I did everything mentioned in #3 and then restarted my system before re-installing.

Interestingly, after doing all of the above and then reinstalling the program, the first time I run it I am STILL greeted with my old Location settings instead of being prompted to choose an new location!  I would also like to add that my wife is running Ubuntu 10.10 and she was able to change her location data with no trouble whatsoever.

The short version of this question would be: how do I change my Location in Weather Indicator on Ubuntu 11.10?  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I would also accept a solution that lets me re-install the application in a brand-new state so I could just add my Location instead of adding a second one or removing the first one, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue - however, some suggestions.

- Reset indicator-weather

Indicator weather related configuration is held in an internal database (you can use `dconf-editor` to view in a GUI format).

Thus to reset indicator-weather you can use the following from a terminal:

```
gsettings reset-recursively apps.indicators.weather
```

- Assign *central* to dconf directly

Assuming that I have correctly searched for "baton rouge" and having selected "central" you can write to the internal database directly with these values:

```
gsettings set apps.indicators.weather locations "{'2377529': {'google id': ',,,30554355,-91036771', 'noaa id': 'woot', 'longitude': '-91.0367706', 'yahoo id': u'USLA0510', 'latitude': '30.5543546', 'label': 'Central', 'full name': 'Central, Louisiana, United States'}}"

gsettings set apps.indicators.weather places "[['2377529', 'Central']]"
```

Comment: Where did you search for those JSON values?
I have the same problem. I want location to be Pune, Maharashtra, India.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to know that too. Did you got them form the settings, or did you used an external service?

Answer (score 0):

Go to a working computer that has the "YOUR" locations data and get the locations data as follows:

```
gsettings get apps.indicators.weather locations
```

and

```
gsettings get apps.indicators.weather places
```

Then copy that data to into a text file. Then change `get` to `set` and copy the data to the non-working computer using a text document and USB stick.

This is an example that worked for me.

```
gsettings set apps.indicators.weather locations "{'2383660': {'google id': ',,,39961176,-82998794', 'noaa id': 'woot', 'longitude': '-82.9987942', 'yahoo id': u'USOH0212', 'latitude': '39.9611755', 'label': 'Columbus', 'full name': 'Columbus, Ohio, United States'}}" 
gsettings set apps.indicators.weather places "[['2383660', 'Columbus']]"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a long-standing [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-weather/+bug/821233); there is a PPA at [ppa:weather-indicator-team/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~weather-indicator-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) that actually fixes it, but it doesn't contain up-to-date builds for `trusty`, only earlier; I have some in [my ppa](https://launchpad.net/~davidf/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=trusty)